# Energy of moving particles

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

When particles move through a space with a certain velocity, which kinds of energy do they have?

They should have translational energy because of their motion, right? But do they also have sensible energy and potential energy ?

Comment: *"sensible"* energy?? What's that when it's at home?

Comment: Used from our physics lecturer. Guess he means sensible heat ?

Comment: There's no such term as *sensible* energy or heat.

Comment: Okay, but how about the other types of energy ?

Comment: Moving bodies (particles if you prefer) have *kinetic* ($K$) energy and/or *potential* energy ($U$).

Comment: And translational energy? According to the definition they should have it too?

Comment: Translational energy IS kinetic energy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this as basic as can be read up in Wikipedia etc.

Comment: in French and Spanish "sensible heat" distinguishes the heat which changes the temperature of a body from the latent heat. So it doesn't seem relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

> When particles move through a space with a certain velocity,which kind
>   of energy do they have? They should have translational energy because of their motion or?

Assuming you are referring to particles having rest mass, then they possess kinetic and gravitational potential energy.

Every object in space in moving relative to other objects in space. That means it potentially has macroscopic rotational and translational kinetic energy in the reference frame of some other objects. Its translational and rotational kinetic energy is that due to the motions of the center of mass of the collection of atoms and molecules of the object.

Likewise no object is completely isolated from the gravitational fields of other objects in space, since the range of gravity is infinite. Therefore every object has macroscopic gravitational potential energy as a function of their relative position to other objects.

> But do they also have sensible energy and potential energy ?

If by "sensible energy" you mean the energy of an object at the microscopic level, which we generally refer to as internal energy, then the answer to that is yes also. At the microscopic level every object consists of atoms and molecules that are constantly in translational, rotational and/or vibrational random motion, with the possible exception of atoms and molecules at absolute zero temperature. Atoms and molecules also have microscopic potential energy due to intermolecular and atomic forces.

In summary, the total energy of an object is the sum of its internal microscopic kinetic and potential energy and external macroscopic kinetic and potential energy with respect to an external frame of reference.

Hope this helps.